# Charindex not working when using two variables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm using two cursors in SQL Server 2008 R2 to work with two lists of values returned from `Select` statements. I read the first value from list tofind1 into a variable find1 and a value from list tosearch1 into a variable search1.

The underlying variable types in the tables are `nvarchar` of length 10 and 255 respectively. The variables are defined as the same length `nvarchar`.

I'm testing it with two strings similar to this:

- find1 = 'bill'
- search1 = 'bill,fred,mary'
- When I try `charindex(find1, search1)` it returns 0. This is incorrect.
- When I try `charindex('bill',search1)` it returns 1. This is correct.

When I just run the following code, both pairs of statements work fine:

```
DECLARE @search1 nvarchar(255);
DECLARE @find1 nvarchar(10);

set @find1 = 'bill'
set @search1 = 'bill,fred,mary'

select charindex(@find1,@search1)
select charindex('bill','bill,fred,mary')

if 'bill,fred,mary' like '%bill%'
    print 'Yay'

if @search1 like '%' + @find1 + '%'
    print 'Yes'
```

Is there something about selecting values into a cursor then assigning it to a variable that messes with its data type so `CHARINDEX` and `LIKE` won't work? I've trying using `CAST` functions to triply make sure that the variables are all seen as `nvarchar`.

Comment: Since the variables `@find1` and `@search1` are `nvarchar`, you should use the `N'..'` prefix notation to set them to `nvarchar`: `set @find1 = N'bill'` - otherwise, you might have implicit conversions happening that produce unexpected results. Same in `CHARINDEX`- if you're using `nvarchar`, you should add the `N` prefix to **all** string literals

Comment: The string literals are only for testing and illustration, and the string literals work perfectly. It is when I do the following that it doesn't work: `FETCH NEXT FROM CursorNames INTO @find1`. I'm doing this to populate @find1 and @search1 and using these variables in the charindex function that doesn't work.

Comment: Is there anyway you can get the actual values where this is not happening, perhaps in addition to running DATALENGTH(@find1) and DATALENGTH(@search1) to make sure there isn't extra whitespace / control characters that could be causing an issue here?